# Why Get-AdminFlow failed to return all the flows

Tags: powershell, power-automate

I have Power Platform administrator permission and recently I used Get-AdminFlow cmdlet to list all the flows under our tenants. The cmdlet is working and listed a lot of flows.

However I found about 70% of desktop flows are missing in the list by  Get-AdminFlow. I can see all of them under https://make.powerautomate.com/.

Why is it?

Comment: Don't know, but when I experience stuff like this I find running Fiddler to see what api calls are being made by the PowerShell cmdlets can often give an insight. eg endpoints, filters, errors etc. You can then take the api requests and play with them in a http request tool such as Postman

Comment: @PaulLucas there is [Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "ipv6.msftconnecttest.com" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known  during the PowerShell running. No error at the PS screen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in PowerShell module PowerApps: get-AdminFlow: if your flow has been disabled on import, you should turn it on and off to see it.
I've tried:
Get-adminflow

return all but not your "xxx" (disabled flow on import into solution)

If you get the flow by name you'll see it : Get-AdminFlow -Flowname "xxx"

Thks MSFT :D

Comment: Hi @no2cl, I confirmed with MS support that desktop flow is not supported. So it is normal for powershell not returning result for desktop flows.